# Using 'en' and the noun it refers to in the same sentence

Tags: pronoms, en

I have a friend who recently wrote to me and used the following sentence:

> Je n'en pouvais plus de cet exil.

I understand the meaning, but I remain confused about the use of *en*. As I've used it before, I would have used *en* to replace something that is introduced by *de* (e.g. *J'ai mangé des pommes.* --> *J'en ai mangé.*) or a countable noun that was previously introduced and clear to the reader/listener (e.g. *J'en ai un.*) In this case, it isn't clear to me if *en* is referring to *cet exil*, in which case, why is *cet exil* still necessary in this sentence? He hadn't mentioned this before, so *Je n'en pouvais plus* would have been confusing to me. Mainly, I am looking for help to deconstruct this sentence and to understand the use of *en* in this case, and when it is used in addition to the noun/concept it is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*n'en  plus pouvoir* est une expression, voir le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pouvoir) :

> − N'en plus pouvoir. Être abattu, à bout de forces. Synon. pop. et fam. être sur les genoux (v. genou), sur les rotules (v. rotule), au bout du rouleau*.N'en plus pouvoir de fatigue, de chaleur. Robert se laisse tomber au pied d'un arbre: Ah! de l'eau, mes amis. Je n'en puis plus, un peu d'eau, si cela est possible (La Martelière,Robert, 1793, v, 1, p.55).
>
> ♦ Au fig. Être excédé. Écoute, Edmond, il faut que tu saches... Je n'en peux plus de ces mensonges (Aragon,Beaux quart., 1936, p.348).
>
> ♦ P. ext., fam. Être écroulé (de rire). N'en plus pouvoir (de rire).
> Rem. Claudel emploie la forme arch. puit et avec un suj. désignant une chose: Face à l'ouragan, il me manquait encore l'horreur (...) de ce bateau pourri qui n'en puit plus (Le Figaro littéraire, 7 mars 1953 cité par Grev., 32, p.674, § 614, 12o, note ds Dupré 1972).

Comment: Thanks @Toto ! I'll check this reference before posting next time.